# Condition Based Subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

There is a tabular report with 3 columns as follows table1.column, table2.column and an expression which is the difference of table1.column and table2.column . I want to create a subscription to send email when the difference of table1.column and table2.column > 10. Any ideas on how to implement this event based subscription? (This table has only one record.)

Comment: Thanks for your response Anup. Can you please mention the steps?

Comment: I see you have asked 10 previous questions and looks like some got resolved too. If it helped you, mark them as an answer. It will encourage the people to answer the questions. It will also help your reputation. Once you reach 75 you can also bounty on your questions.

Comment: AnupAgrawal: Sure I will.